# Compatibility of MathJax extension and JetPack

Tags: shortcode, plugin-jetpack, plugin-mathjax

I just installed the [MathJax Extension](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mathjax-latex/) for Wordpress because I did not really like the way the math were rendered with the `[latex]` tags provided with the JetPack.

If I use the classic `$$`, the blog renders the equation using MathJax. However, if I keep using `[latex]` the JetPack function seems to be used, and I can't find a way to only remove this feature from the jetpack?

Is there any known issue in having the two methods at the same time?

Is there a way to remove only this feature from the jetpack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Remove](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_shortcode) Jetpack’s shortcode handler:

```
remove_shortcode( 'latex', 'latex_shortcode' );
```

I don’t know when exactly the shortcode is registered, you have to find the best execution point (action) to remove it.